# Facebook Insights API + Get all metric fields (with definition) + page object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

with Facebook Graph Api we can get all the fields definition by adding "?metadata=1" in the query.
With Facebook Insights I don't see how to retrieve all the metric fields (with their definition, code...)

Have you any idea to get / download this list in a usable format (csv, xml, text..)

Thanks.

Comment: user28220 did you ever find a solution to this?